# Possible to implement dynamically-typed linked list in safe Rust?

Tags: rust, dynamic, linked-list

Is it possible to implement a dynamically-typed linked list in safe Rust?

The meaning of dynamically-typed linked list:

```
Node(56.7) -> Node("hello") -> Node(77) -> ...
```

I am doing this as an exercise, have tried different approaches to no avail, using Traits. Therefore doubting the possibility of doing this in Safe Rust.

Comment: Implementing a linked list is probably not a very good exercise. https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/index.html (But the "handle different types for values" part might teach you something useful.)

Comment: There being a whole dedicated tutorial about implementing linked lists seems contrary to your point @Caesar, but I think that you got a point somewhere, focus on the different tasks separately rather than merging both at the same time. Develop a linked list for a specific type, develop a dynamic type, only if you got both you should attempt a dynamically-typed linked list.

Comment: I'd rather call the too many linked lists series a cautionary tale than a tutorial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## If your list has to work with any type

You can use the `Any` trait or better yet another [object-safe](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/traits.html#object-safety) trait which has the functionality you need from items in the list.

```rust
enum Node {
    Nil,
    Node {
        value: Box<dyn std::any::Any>,
        next: Box<Node>,
    },
}

impl std::fmt::Debug for Node {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> Result<(), std::fmt::Error> {
        match self {
            Node::Nil => write!(f, "Nil"),
            Node::Node { value, next } => {
                if let Some(value) = value.downcast_ref::<f64>() {
                    write!(f, "Node({value}) -> {next:?}")
                } else if let Some(value) = value.downcast_ref::<i32>() {
                    write!(f, "Node({value}) -> {next:?}")
                } else if let Some(value) = value.downcast_ref::<&str>() {
                    write!(f, "Node({value:?}) -> {next:?}")
                } else {
                    write!(f, "Node(<unknown type>) -> {next:?}")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let list = Node::Node {
        value: Box::new(56.7),
        next: Box::new(Node::Node {
            value: Box::new("hello"),
            next: Box::new(Node::Node {
                value: Box::new(77),
                next: Box::new(Node::Nil),
            }),
        }),
    };
    dbg!(list);
}
```

will output something like `[src/main.rs:39] list = Node(56.7) -> Node("hello") -> Node(77) -> Nil` to stderr.

#### Pros

- Works with any object (implementing the trait).
- Every `Node` has the size of two `Box`es no matter the types you put into the list.

#### Cons

- Using `downcast*` can become very awkward fast, and there isn't really much you can do with a `dyn Any` otherwise.
- Necessary additional indirection of `Box`.

## If you know the types that end up in the list

You can use an enum with every possible type:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
enum DynamicType {
    Float(f64),
    Int(i32),
    Str(&'static str),
}
enum Node {
    Nil,
    Node {
        value: DynamicType,
        next: Box<Node>,
    },
}

impl std::fmt::Debug for Node {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> Result<(), std::fmt::Error> {
        match self {
            Node::Nil => write!(f, "Nil"),
            Node::Node { value, next } => write!(f, "Node({value:?}) -> {next:?}"),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    use DynamicType::*;
    let list = Node::Node {
        value: Float(56.7),
        next: Box::new(Node::Node {
            value: Str("hello"),
            next: Box::new(Node::Node {
                value: Int(77),
                next: Box::new(Node::Nil),
            }),
        }),
    };
    dbg!(list);
}
```

#### Pros

- You can `match` and know instantly what type you're dealing with.
- No indirection, the data is stored directly in the `Node`s.

#### Cons

- If the `DynamicType` contains a variety of sizes you might end up wasting a lot of space on `Node`s.
- You have to know every type to put in up front.

Comment: Does using `Any` have a lot of benefits over using something like [`serde_json::Value`](https://docs.rs/serde_json/latest/serde_json/value/enum.Value.html)? In the end, you need a "switch" statement somewhere that handles the different possible types.

Comment: An enum requires upstream adding an explicit case for each supported type. `Any` gives the user control over the internal values, though at the cost of gnarlier and less efficient retrieval (bunch of `downcast_ref`), as well as the boxing requirement.