# Implementing a dynamic-typed LinkedList in Rust

Tags: rust, types, dynamic, linked-list

This is a follow-up on the question asked here: [Possible to implement dynamically-typed linked list in safe Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74973472/possible-to-implement-dynamically-typed-linked-list-in-safe-rust)

I successfully implemented a dynamic type LinkedList using the `std::any::Any` trait.

However, I want to challenge myself by trying to implement it in another way, e.g. using generic type - Node where T can be any type, u32, u64, String, ...

Example

```
Node<String> -> Node<u32> -> Node<u64> -> Node<String> -> ...
```

My approach is to use a trait called `Next` to give `Node<T>` the ability to "go next".

`Node<T>` looks like this.

```rust
struct Node<T> {
    data: T,
    next: Option<Rc<RefCell<dyn Next>>>,
}
```

The trait `Next` looks like this.

```rust
pub trait Next {
    fn borrow_next(&self) -> Option<Ref<dyn Next>>;
    fn set_next(&mut self, next: Rc<RefCell<dyn Next>>);
}
```

These are the implementation of Next for any Node.

```rust
impl<T> Next for Node<T> {
    fn set_next(&mut self, next: Rc<RefCell<dyn Next>>) {
        self.next = Some(next);
    }

    fn borrow_next(&self) -> Option<Ref<dyn Next>> {
        match &self.next {
          None => None,
          Some(stmt) => Some(stmt.borrow()),
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the implementations for the actual struct `Node<T>`.

```rust
impl<T> Node<T> {
    pub fn new<P>(data: P) -> Node<P> {
        Node::<P> { data, next: None }
    }

    pub fn new_wrapped<P>(data: P) -> Rc<RefCell<Node<P>>> {
        Rc::new(RefCell::new(Node::<P>::new(data)))
    }

    pub fn into_wrapped(self) -> Rc<RefCell<Self>> {
        Rc::new(RefCell::new(self))
    }

    pub fn borrow_data(&self) -> &T {
        &self.data
    }

    pub fn set_data(&mut self, data: T) {
        self.data = data;
    }
}
```

Lastly, the declaration and its implementations of methods of struct `DynLinkedList`, holding two fields, `head` and `tail`, look like this.

```rust
struct DynLinkedList {
    head: Option<Rc<RefCell<dyn Next>>>,
    tail: Option<Rc<RefCell<dyn Next>>>,
}


impl DynLinkedList {
    pub fn new_empty() -> Self {
        Self {
            head: None,
            tail: None,
        }
    }

    pub fn new_with_node(node: Rc<RefCell<dyn Next>>) -> Self {
        Self {
            head: Some(node.clone()),
            tail: Some(node),
        }
    }

    pub fn append(&mut self, node: Rc<RefCell<dyn Next>>) {
        self.tail.take().map_or_else(
            || self.head = Some(node.clone()),
            |old_tail| old_tail.borrow_mut().set_next(node.clone()),
        );
        self.tail = Some(node);
    }
}
```

Here comes the problem:

I am unable to access the `data` field of `Node<T>` as it is being treated as a trait object `dyn Next` by the compiler.

For example, this test would not work:

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
  use super::*;

  #[test]
  fn test_dynll_new_with_node() {
    let node = Node::<u32>::new(77_u32);
    let dynll = DynLinkedList::new_with_node(node.into_wrapped());
    assert_eq!(&dynll.head.unwrap().borrow().borrow_data(), &77);
    assert_eq!(&dynll.tail.unwrap().borrow().borrow_data(), &77)
  }
}
```

The compiler error is:

```rust
error[E0599]: no method named `borrow_data` found for struct `Ref<'_, (dyn Next + 'static)>` in the current scope
   --> src/dyn_ll_idea_five.rs:125:47
    |
125 |     assert_eq!(&*dynll.head.unwrap().borrow().borrow_data(), &77);
    |                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `Ref<'_, (dyn Next + 'static)>`
```

But, when the `.borrow()` after `.unwrap()` returns, it should return an object of type Node which would have the method `.borrow_data()`, how can I let Rust know that this is the case? Thank you.

I would effectively want to be able to do this:

```
let mut list = DynLinkedList::new();

list.push_front("hello".to_string());
list.push_back("world".to_string());
list.push_front(123);
list.push_back(456);

assert_eq!(list.pop_front(), Some("hello".to_string()));
assert_eq!(list.pop_back(), Some("world".to_string()));
assert_eq!(list.pop_front(), Some(123));
assert_eq!(list.pop_back(), Some(456));
```

Comment: You can only use a traits methods on trait objects, you have to move the relevant methods into the `Next` trait.

Comment: Okay, but how would I get the `data` field from the `dyn Next` trait object? I might try to define a generic method `borrow_data<T>(&self) -> Ref<T>` but that would mean `dyn Next` cannot be object-safe anymore. If `dyn Next` cannot be object-safe, how can I have a "type-less" `DynLinkedList` struct for my dynamic typed implementation?

Comment: You can return a trait object describing the type you want or just `Ref<dyn Any>` for anything. That's a reason why trait objects are somewhat problematic, they lock you into dynamic dispatch and static dispatch is hard/impossible to reach again.

Answer (score 3):

Well, nowhere in the definition of `trait Next` does it talk about objects of type `Node`. Thus, how would the compiler ever know that you can call `borrow_data` on it? That's where you'd do the downcast via the `Any` trait.

What's more, the compiler would also want to know *which* sort of Node we're talking about. `Node<i32>` or `Node<String>` or what? And that's downright impossible because your list is dynamic and hence whatever type is contained within a node is also dynamic.

Let's take your example:

```rust
Node<String> -> Node<u32> -> Node<u64> -> Node<String> -> ...
```

So if that's your list, then, using very rough ugly pseudocode, what about this:

```rust
let x: String = my_list.head.borrow_data();
let y: u32 = my_list.head.next.borrow_data();
let z: u64 = my_list.head.next.next.borrow_data();
```

You see the problem here? How is the compiler to know, at compile time, that the third item in the list has type `u64`? This just isn't a case where generics work in the way you want it.

Comment: Well said. `Node<dyn Any>` is a much simpler way to achieve the behavior they want.

Comment: ```
error[E0599]: no method named `downcast_ref` found for struct `Ref<'_, (dyn Next + 'static)>` in the current scope
   --> src/dyn_ll_idea_five.rs:125:47
    |
125 |     assert_eq!(&*dynll.head.unwrap().borrow().downcast_ref::<Node<u32>>().borrow_data(), &77);
    |                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `Ref<'_, (dyn Next + 'static)>```

Even if I try downcast_ref::<Node<u32>>(), it still says method is not found even though trait `Any` is implemented for `Ref`.

Comment: `downcast_ref` isn't actually part of the trait interface of `Any` though; it's part of the _implementation_, and so I suspect the issue here is that the particular `Ref` doesn't fit the various type and trait bounds to be considered for that implementation.